# Are there runtime errors(= exceptions) that do not generate a traceback in python?

Tags: python, runtime-error, traceback

Are there runtime errors(= exceptions) that do not generate a traceback?
If yes, why do some runtime errors not generate tracebacks? could you give some examples?

Comment: would like to know, but have never heard of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a very large value to [sys.setrecursionlimit()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), then enter an infinite recursive loop. The interpreter will crash without a traceback in that case.

However, that's only because the call to `setrecursionlimit()` effectively disables the fail-safe mechanism that would have turned a potential stack overflow into a Python exception.

Comment: I can't choose between your answer and Andrew Walker's answer. Both are good answers and assure me that I don't have to worry much not having a traceback when encountering a runtime Error.

Comment: @Bentley, thank you for your comment :) However, you should still accept one of our answers to fully resolve your question (and prevent it from appearing in the `unanswered` tab). The [current consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164403) is `to accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally`. Rest assured that neither Andrew nor Ned nor I will think ill of you for choosing one over the other, as this is the way things work here. *(If you're really desperate, I suggest flipping a coin ;)*

Comment: I chose your answer because I think it would have been slightly more likely to encounter your case. I also found the error more interesting. Sorry Andrew Walker!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I can think of at least one: segmentation faults.

```
>>> import faulthandler
>>> faulthandler._sigsegv()
Segmentation fault
```

The faulthandler module is specifically designed to help in such situations.

```
>>> import faulthandler
>>> faulthandler.enable()
>>> faulthandler._sigsegv()
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0xb76fe6c0
 File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no Python exceptions that don't produce tracebacks.  As the other answers show, you can crash CPython hard, which don't produce tracebacks.  If you could explain your interest in this, we might have more information.